# Combobox in WPF unable to add hardcode values with database values

Tags: c#, wpf

XAML Code:

```
        <ComboBox  x:Name="CbLinge" HorizontalAlignment="right" Margin="0,150,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300" Height="25" RenderTransformOrigin="1.018,0.565 " 
              ItemsSource="{Binding GetLinge}" 
               DisplayMemberPath="Linge" 
               SelectedValuePath="Linge" 
               SelectedValue="{Binding FinishedManual.Ligne}"/>
```

C# Code:

```
  public void _fillLinge()
        {
            List<FinishedManualPrintingLinge> linge = _finishedProductService.GetFinishedManualLinge().ToList();
            foreach (var item in linge)
            {
                GetLinge.Add(item);
            }

        }
```

By This piece of code,I'm able to get the values from database and able to display in Dropdown.

Problem:
The dropdown list for "Ligne" is linked to data available in order table. But if any order for the line, then it is not visible in drop-down "Ligne". So, it should be hardcoded/ populated by (1,4,6,7,8,9,10).

Now, I am not sure how to display the hardcode values if order : x is selected.

Comment: What do you mean by _But if any order for the line, then it is not visible in drop-down "Ligne"._?

Comment: try to filter as this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/16938351/713789

Comment: @Alain: example we have 1 more drop-down above which is displaying orders. Now if user select the order which doesn't have and existing value of linge. So in that case my drop- down will show (1,4,6,7,8,9,10) values.

Comment: So you want to have a `FallBack` value for your collection `Binding`. It is easy enough, also you clicked on combobox and rotated it a bit, you don't need `SelectedValuePath` when you use `SelectedValue`.

Comment: Have you had any luck with this?

Answer (score 0):

**OPTION 1**
Display a hardcoded set of values:
Here is how I have done it:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding GetLinge, TargetNullValue='123456789', FallbackValue='123456789'}"/>
```

In your case you would use the `TargetNullValue` to populate the values. The `10` might be a bit tricky as the string is `IEnumerable` so it will pick single characters from the array. But I think this will push you in the right direction.

**OPTION 2**
Another option is to modify your `public void _fillLinge()` method and let it return default values if there aren't any found.

**OPTION 3**
Another Option would be to use a converter which would then supply the default items instead of modifying the `public void _fillLinge()` method.
The choice is yours.